# VM Corrupted, what's the next step?

Tags: hyper-v, virtual-machines

So one of our older VM's, which usually has no issues, is giving this error now when starting. It keeps going in a loop restarting and turning off with this error message.

[image]

I figure it's probably some issue with the VHD corrupting.

What's the next step? How would I run CHKDISK if I can't even load into the VM? This is with Hyper-V on Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: What's your backup situation?

Comment: Spin up a new VM and recover from backups ?

Comment: Did you do a VM hardware-level upgrade?  Or change the storage controller mode?  0x7B usually is a Disk Controller driver issue.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest booting to installation media for the guest OS and attempting a chkdsk or recovery from there. Where you go next will depend on the results of that...

Comment: How do you do this in Hyper-V? just starting the VM doesn't allow me to do that.

Answer (score 3):

The VM is not likely corrupted, you would treat this like any other 0x7B error, which is storage controller. Load the ISO for the OS and boot from it, then run CHKDSK/ R like the error suggests.

Did this VM have the latest Integration Services loaded for your version of Hyper-V? You can attempt a re-install of Integration Services in Safe Mode, and this may very well correct the issue.

Was this originally a P2V conversion? If so, look here:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/michs/archive/2011/09/16/p2v-migration-issues-with-hyper-v-stop-0x0000007b.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Another great option if we are solely talking about the VHD (I know it could be just the VM to which user1467163's suggestion could help with that too) is to attach this VHD to a known working VM as a secondary drive.  Once it's attached to a good VM, THEN perform a chkdsk /r and sfc /scannow on the possibly corrupted drive and let them both finish.  If there is anything wrong it will be fixed with the switches I've recommended and then you can recreate a new VM and attach this freshly fixed VHD to it.

Just another option. The other two are where I would go too if this didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If it were me, where I have complete control of my environment, here is what I would do:
Get screenshots of ALL settings for the VM in Hyper-V
Shut down the VM if it is in any state besides "Off"
On the host, copy all VHD's to a safe backup location
Delete the VM in Hyper-V manager
Create a new VM (Call it the same name if you want)
**Copy** the VHD's you backed up into the new VM directory where they belong
Attach the VHD's to the new VM

This is how you rule out VM corruption.
I hope this is on-target with your problem- I could not read the error because the image host was flooded.